# BMP180 ERROR read

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a project with an ESP8266 and a BMP 180 Following this code

The first read is everything okay ..but after just 214° celsius

Temperature  22.70 Celsius
Pressure  102686 Pascal

Temperature  214.50 Celsius
 Pressure  235302 Pascal
Temperature  214.50 Celsius
 Pressure  235302 Pascal

```
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>

    Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;

    void setup() 
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      //Wire.begin (4, 5);
      if (!bmp.begin()) 
      {
        Serial.println("Could not find BMP180 or BMP085 sensor at 0x77");
        while (1) {}
      }
    }

    void loop() 
    {
      Serial.print("Temperature = ");
      Serial.print(bmp.readTemperature());
      Serial.println(" Celsius");

      Serial.print("Pressure = ");
      Serial.print(bmp.readPressure());
      Serial.println(" Pascal");

  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The BMP180 has an operating temperature range of -40 to +85C, so if the temperature is up at 214.50 you're well outside of the range it's supposed to operate in and it's not surprising you're seeing errors.

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1603

You'll need a different sensor if you want to use it at those temperatures.